# Не отображает изображение в браузере

Tags: html, изображения

Вроде написано все правильно, делала по урокам в интернете.

Браузер не отображает изображение, видна только рамка и значок картинки.
Папка `images` находится на одном уровне с `html` документом.

```
<img src="images/flower.jpg" width="420" height="240" >
```

Comment: Дайте скриншот где лежит html документ

Comment: А что в консоли? F12 нажмите и перейдите на вкладку консоль

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<img src="./images/flower.jpg" width="420" height="240">
```

Тут точка обозначает непосредственно ту директорию, в которой находиться файл с этой командой

```
<img src="../images/flower.jpg" width="420" height="240">
```

Двоеточие обозначает предидущую директорию

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Откройте инструменты разработки, какую ошибку пишет инспектор?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: А файл по адресу `images/flower.jpg` есть?

Comment: C:\Users\Аня\Desktop\HTML\images - вот путь до файла

Comment: Добавьте в Ваш вопрос структуру проекта, где что лежит лучше в виде дерева

Comment: где лежит html файл

Comment: Проверьте расширение картинки. Может она имеет расширение png (или какое-то другое), а не jpg. Иногда расширение может быть JPEG и некоторые браузеры сообщают ошибку. Пришлите линк картинки и веб-страницы с картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Вы открываете html-файл как файл, не используя сервер. поэтому ваш относительный путь не срабатывает. Вам нужно вставить тег [base](http://htmlbook.ru/html/base) и указать там путь до вашей папки с html, должно помочь

`<base href="file://c:/path/to/html">`

Comment: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7592